# Draw a square using two clicks, one to set start, and another for edge length

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How can I code turtle to draw a square like in paint, using two clicks -- one to set the starting point and a second click for the defined edge length?

I wanna: click once to set the center of a square; move the mouse to define the edge-length of the square; click a second time to draw the square with the defined edge-length and center point. But I couldn't manage it; do you have any ideas? I also tried to create a color palette so I can change the drawing color of my turtle if I click on one of the colors but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import turtle



beni=turtle.Screen()
beni.setup(900,700,)

t=turtle.Turtle()

#color palette
t1=turtle.Turtle()
t1.shape("circle")
t1.color("blue")
t1.penup()
t1.setposition(250, 300)

t2=turtle.Turtle()
t2.shape("circle")
t2.color("red")
t2.penup()
t2.setposition(220,300)

t3=turtle.Turtle()
t3.shape("circle")
t3.color("green")
t3.penup()
t3.setposition(280, 300)


def funktion(x,y):
    t.color("green")
    t.pencolor("green")

    t3.onclick(funktion)


def funktion(x, y):
    t.color("blue")
    t.pencolor("blue")

    t2.onclick(funktion)


def funktion(x, y):
    t.color("red")
    t.pencolor("red")

    t1.onclick(funktion)

#freehandmode
def freehandmode(x, y):
    t.ondrag(None)
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.ondrag(freehandmode)

t.ondrag(freehandmode)

#linemode
class Drawer:
    def __init__(self):
       self.drawing = False

    def click(self, x, y):
        if self.drawing:
            turtle.down()
            turtle.goto(x, y)
            self.drawing = False
        else:
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x, y)
            self.drawing = True

d = Drawer()
beni.onclick(d.click)

#squaremode





turtle.up()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this, I'm going to do it by swapping event handlers so the first and second clicks have different meanings.  I'm going to use circles (pick the center, then the edge) to keep my example simple and leave some geometry for you to ponder:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_circle(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)
    center = turtle.position()
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(center) - 90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(turtle.distance(center))
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.clearstamps()
    screen.onclick(pick_center)

def pick_center(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.stamp()
    screen.onclick(draw_circle)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.shapesize(0.5)
turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(pick_center)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you pls tell me how this exactly works cause Im kinda confused and do you know why my colors dont work? plus I think you misunderstood cause I wanted to know how to draw a square with two klicks not a circle but thanks I really appreciate it